# Unittests - Python - Being in a subfolder, how can i import from another subfolder at the same level?

Tags: python, github-actions, python-import, python-unittest, cicd

Under my GitHub repository, imagine I have 2 subfolders, one holds my lambda code (subfolderA), and the other holds my unittest (subfolderB) that I want to run against that lambda code - structure below...

GitHub repo -
subfolderA -
apples.py
**init**.py
subfolderB -
unittest.py
**init**.py
**init**.py

How can I import functions from within apples.py, from the unittest.py file?

I have tried both:

from subfolderA.apples import colour_of_apple
from ..subfolderA.apples import colour_of_apple

but I keep getting:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apples' when I run this on GitHub, and
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subfolderA' when I run it locally

I have got the relevant **init**.py files within my folders and within the root of my GitHub repo, why isn't it recognising the folders as modules, or finding my apples file? I would ideally like to get this working on GitHub, as I am trying to fit the unittests into my CICD process.

Am I doing the imports wrong? Am I missing something?